# Calling a db connection inside a class

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a problem regarding my mysql connection. I need to access the connection inside a class. How do I do it? Even if I try to include the connection file, or the connection variable $con0 inside the class, it has no value so I get an error.

Connection.php

```
<?php
$username = " ";
$password = "";
$hostname = " ";    
$con = mysql_connect()
?>
```

model.php

```
<?php

include(connection.php);
class model{

function needTheConnection($uid){
$q = "SELECT x from  DB.table WHERE id = '" . $uid . "'";
$res  = mysql_query($q);
}

}
?>
```

This gives me the "mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource".

What is wrong?

Thanks,
tinks

Comment: this code won't give you such error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing part of your code.  We know this based on the error message.  This line:

```
$res  = mysql_query($q);
```

Probably actually looks like this in your code:

```
$res  = mysql_query($q, $con);
```

Am I right?  If that's the case, the issue is that `$con` isn't accessible from within that function or class instance.  The easy way to fix this in your case is to simply remove it.  The MySQL client will automagically use the last connection made from your script.

Really though, you should consider a different design pattern.  For what its worth, I often just stick my DB resource in `$GLOBALS['db']`.  This is not considered a pure OOP way to do things, but for many applications, it is suitable.

Finally, $5 says you are wide open to SQL injections.  Learn how to do prepared queries with PDO, or at least escape your data before someone steals your entire database and brings havok to your site.

Comment: hi! yes you're right, i missed out the $con. i will look into $GLOBAL thanks.. and you mean i should always use mysql_real_escape_string() for security?

Comment: @tinks no, mysql_real_escape_string() has nothing to do with security. But you have to use it when needed.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel i was referring to this one "Learn how to do prepared queries with PDO, or at least escape your data before someone steals your entire database and brings havok to your site."... 
mysql_real_escape_string()  can be of help right..

Comment: @tinks no. but I am tired to explain the same thing a dozen times a day. do yourself a favor and search this site on the matter

Answer (score 1):

```
class model { 
  function __construct(&$db) {
    $this->db=$db;
  }
  function needTheConnection($uid){ 
    $q = "SELECT x from DB.table"; 
    $res  = mysql_query($q,$this->db); 
  } 
}

$model = new model($conn);
```

Comment: hi, the $res is the connection right? not the result of the query?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel.. its giving me this error  Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated; If you would like to pass it by reference, modify the declaration of [runtime function name]().  If you would like to enable call-time pass-by-reference, you can set allow_call_time_pass_reference to true in your INI file in

Comment: my function name was just getConnection(){} that returns the $con.. do i need to modify it/